# Google doesn't send Push-Notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API in my application.

The problem that I faced is that Google doesn't send me Push-Notifications.

1. I setup my app here https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Verified domain: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification
3. Watched calendar: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/watch and got successful response.

However, having done all of this, no push-notifications are received by my web-hook. It seems that Google just doesn't send them. Maybe I missed some step? I use https URL.

Comment: Did you [create a notification channel](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#creating-notification-channels)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the URL that I used for PUSH-NOTIFICATIONS wasn't whitelisted and if it was requested from other network(e.g. Google), then the request couldn't be processed.

Therefore, if there is such a problem, consider checking your URL availability outside your network. It should be accessible from anywhere and by anyone.

Comment: I'd assume there's a way  to whitelist google's API without opening it up to anyone